# Ubiquity of language... lost in translation

Tags: domain-driven-design

I found two collapsing problems :

- You should use the same language
  between domain experts and
  development teams (DDD)
- You should
  use English for naming in your code
  (.Net Design guidelines)

*What if the domain experts don't speak English ?*

Comment: You'll want to check out the answers to this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553082/do-you-code-variables-in-your-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Speaking the same language between the teams will foster understanding. However, does the DDD item mean literal "language" (tongue), or "terminology"?
- Using English for coding is a suggestion, not a requirement.
- As long as your development team can translate the code operation/intent, I don't see the issue.

Comment: We're actually using English for coding, so we translate domain terms for coding. It is not really a burden, but it adds a mental step when speaking

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me you should use native language for business (like customer, order etc) and english for technical terms (like get, set etc).
If you start translating your business words, you have to go through a mental step and furthermore you sometimes get two different translations for two things - in other words it's a mess.
Now you only have to find out what is a business term and what is a technical term...

Answer (score 1):

We use the domain language (lawyerly German) for domain concepts and English for technical concepts. This leads to funny-looking class names, but on balance, it's a win.

More detail in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553082/do-you-code-variables-in-your-language/553164#553164) to a closely related question.